# How does Jhipster generate swagger info?

Tags: jhipster

How/where does the swagger json for the swagger ui get generated ?

I thought maybe it was Springfox that was automatically doing it, but if I add a field without using the Jhipster 'entity creation' feature the field does not show up in the swagger docs. So obviously something generates it pre build..

Comment: No it's only made by Springfox by introspecting controllers and interpreting annotations on methods and parameters

Comment: @gael at what point does this happen though ?

Comment: It happens at application startup, try setting a breakpoint in springfox.documentation.builders.DocumentationBuilder